# Posso usar o tools.jar no ClassPath do meu projeto Java?

Tags: java, jdk

Eu gostaria de saber se tem algum problema, já que ele é parte do JDK, ou mesmo se é necessário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o `tools.jar` ao classpath se quiser fazer uso das classes.

Tal arquivo contém classes usadas para o desenvolvimento de programas Java, tal como classes do compilador Java.

Ele também é distribuido com o JDK, portanto, diferentemente das classes do JRE que estão presentes automaticamente para o programa, você não tem garantia nem de que essa biblioteca vai estar presente no ambiente do usuário. É por isso que algumas ferramentas exigem você usar um JDK.

Referência: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não é necessário, ele já faz parte do JDK.
Apenas verifique se onde for rodar a aplicação, qual o JAVA_HOME esta setado.